# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes after login, usb keybord/mouse disabled. computer has NvidiaGeforce graphics, Amd athalon II

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, amd-processor

After attempting to log in ubuntu becomes unresponsive, NOthing works, including the power button. The only way to turn off the computer is to unplug and try again... resulting in the same thing again. Tried several reinstalls, but no change.

Comment: can you login to terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) or TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F1)?

Comment: could you output the command: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` I'm assuming it loads with Nouveau driver onboard, I'm using Amd with Nvidia it works flawlessly on 14.04 but it installed with nouveau onboard and I had troubles too. I'll walk you through, just answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is an incompatibility with your computer try to find if your computer is ubuntu certified. You may report a bug and Could you tell me if it works from a live CD?
Also I found an article in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide and it says "Wubi uses a virtual disk that is sensitive to forced shutdowns. If Ubuntu appears to be frozen please refer to: How to reboot cleanly even when the keyboard/mouse are frozen". Even if you did not use wubi please look at this page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_to_reboot_cleanly_even_when_the_keyboard.2BAC8-mouse_are_frozen

Comment: I previously had ubuntu 12.04 installed with no problems, although my PC hardware is not listed on the compatibility list. I tried using the clean reboot guide and tried all of the commands waiting a minute or two between them, and none seemed to have any effect, the same goes for the power button on the case, as it will not turn it off either (even after holding for 10-30 seconds). Also Live CD does not work simply freezes after trying.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that your computer has a problem running 14.04. Could you tell me more information about this computer? Also try to find facts about ubuntu freezing on search engines. Try to use an other desktop edition like xfce or kde of 14.04 from a live cd if they work your computer will have a problem with only unity.
 I do not have any other ideas. There do not seem anything unusual with your computer for ubuntu. I am not sure but try to use the other bit version (32bit or 64 bit) instead of that you used in a live cd.

Comment: Tried running Kubuntu with the similar results

Comment: Here is a link to all system specs from ubuntu 12.04 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3JBAjKKrGoYNjlMRTcyYTU1MXBadUQ5S0llOUk3cXhreHQ4/edit?usp=sharing                                     to view the file it must be downloaded then can be opened with the browser of your choice (file, download)